# Subset one data frame based on specific numeric intervals from another

Tags: r, syntax, subset

I would like subset `df1` based on values which are outside specific numeric intervals in `df2`.

My input `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- 'name sam1 sam2 sam3  
        AZ1  2.65  2.56  2.65
        AX1  2.22  2.41  2.85
        AX2  2.45  2.45  2.85'
df1 <- read.table(text=df1, header=T)

df2 <- 'name sam1 sam2 sam3  
        AZ1  1  0  1
        AX1  0.75  0.55  1
        AX2  0  0  0.62'
df2 <- read.table(text=df2, header=T)
```

I tried the below code to subset it without success:

```
out <- df1[if(df2 >= 0.90) |if(df2 <= 0.10) | if(df2 <= 0.60 && df2 >= 0.40)]
```

Where I was trying to subset just the `df1` cells which has values above 0.90 **or** below 0.1 **or** between 0.4 to 0.6 (the other way around: NA to the `x` intervals: 0.40 > x > 0.10 and 0.9 > x > 0.6). The expected output is:

```
out <- 'name sam1 sam2 sam3  
            AZ1  2.65  2.56  2.65
            AX1  NA  2.41  2.85
            AX2  2.45  2.45  NA'
out <- read.table(text=out, header=T)
```

I would be grateful for any help with the syntax here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually easier to manually introduce `NA`s. You don't need `if` if there's no code to be evaluated if it's true; inequalities already evaluate to a Boolean. Really, all you need is

```
 df1[((df2 < 0.9) & (df2 > 0.6)) | ((df2 < 0.4) & (df2 > 0.1))] <- NA
```

which changes `df1` so it looks like

```
> df1
  name sam1 sam2 sam3
1  AZ1 2.65 2.56 2.65
2  AX1   NA 2.41 2.85
3  AX2 2.45 2.45   NA
```

With long Boolean tests like this, watch your parentheses, especially if you've got multiple ranges.

---

#### Edit

If called on the `df2` exactly as above, this code will raise warnings

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
> 2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
> 3: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
> 4: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
> ```

because `df2$name` is a factor. Since factors store their values as numbers (mapped to levels), R is warning that it's not performing the inequality operations on those values, which we don't want it to do, anyway. Since it does nothing to the `name` column, the result it what we want regardless of the warnings.

The warnings can be avoided wholly by changing `name` to character, or not turning it into a factor in the first place. Either specify the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table` when you read in the data, or prepend the above line with

```
 df2$name <- as.character(df2$name)
```

Since it's obvious that R won't compare a string and a number with an inequality, it will no longer raise warnings.

Comment: Right, for the `name` column. You could subset around it, but it doesn't actually mess anything up.

Comment: @docendodiscimus If you specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` on import or convert `name` to character, it doesn't raise warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that returns a logical matrix that maps the from the values of df2 and the condtioning intervals using findInterval and then stamps the NA's onto the target dataframe with `is.na<-`

```
 nafunc <- function(z) {sapply(z, function(x) 
      findInterval( as.numeric(x), c(-Inf, 0.10, 0.40, 0.6, 0.9, Inf)) %in% c(2, 4) )}

is.na( df1)  <- nafunc(df2)
df1
#------    
  name sam1 sam2 sam3
1  AZ1 2.65 2.56 2.65
2  AX1   NA 2.41 2.85
3  AX2 2.45 2.45   NA
```

You could also use that function to extract the values from the df1:

```
> df1[ !nafunc(df2) ]
 [1] "AZ1"  "AX1"  "AX2"  "2.65" "2.45" "2.56" "2.41" "2.45" "2.65" "2.85"
```

Unbeautiful, since the process of extraction coerces to a matrix, coercing everything to character. So will try a slightly different sequence of operations:

```
> df1[, 2:4 ][!nafunc(df2)[, 2:4]]
[1] 2.65 2.45 2.56 2.41 2.45 2.65 2.85   # Delivers the first requested result.
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `magrittr` library

```
library(magrittr)

idx <- as.matrix(df2[, -1]) %>% 
       {(.<0.9 & .>0.6) | (.<0.4 & .>0.1)}

df1[, -1][idx] <- NA

df1

   name sam1 sam2 sam3
1  AZ1 2.65 2.56 2.65
2  AX1   NA 2.41 2.85
3  AX2 2.45 2.45   NA
```

Or a shorter but the same answer

```
df1[, -1][df2 %>% .[, -1] %>% as.matrix %>% 
         {(.<0.9 & .>0.6) | (.<0.4 & .>0.1)}] <- NA
```